# Choosing a printer drawer with Python

Tags: python, printing, drawer

I have a kyocera printer with 5 different drawers and I need to create a program with Python that allows you  to choose which drawer will be used.

In order to do that, I need to access the print settings in the control panel, and change the "drawer" option there.

I can only access the printers with the following code:

```
os.system('control.exe /name Microsoft.Printers')
```

I dont seem to have any way to access the settings of the printer itself. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have pywin32 installed, it appears to have that ability, but I personally have never used it.

These two posts might be of some use to you:

[Change printer tray with pywin32](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11045704/change-printer-tray-with-pywin32)

[Python win32print changing advanced printer options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5555453/python-win32print-changing-advanced-printer-options)